# maintain text but eliminate CR LF between tags

Tags: javascript, regex, vbscript, flat-file, ecma262

Fellow Regexers,

I have a flat file full of expressions like:

```
SELECT * FROM CONVENIENT_ONE_LINE_QUERY
"SELECT * FROM THIS_QUERY
WHERE IS_SPREAD_OVER == 123
ORDER BY MULTIPLE_LINES
HAVING AND_IS_BETWEEN_QUOTES"
SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_CONVENIENT_ONE_LINER
```

I want to eliminate the CRLF *between* the quotes and the quotes themselves, so that all my queries are convenient one-liners like that:

```
SELECT * FROM CONVENIENT_ONE_LINE_QUERY
SELECT * FROM THIS_QUERY WHERE IS_SPREAD_OVER == 123 ORDER BY MULTIPLE_LINES HAVING BUT_IS_BETWEEN_QUOTES
SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_CONVENIENT_ONE_LINER
```

Please post the RegEx flavor used in the solution. I'm using TextCrawler, which claims to be ECMA262 (same as VBScript/Javascript) and the closest I came to a solution is something like:

```
(\r\n".*)(.*)\r\n(.*"\r\n)
```

Forgive my n00biness.
Best regards,
Lynx Kepler

Comment: Can you show an example of input and result? I don't get the relation from the first example to the other, since more than quotes and line breaks differ.

Comment: I corrected the input and output, now only quotes and line breaks differ (or should). Essentially I wanna swap each line break that is between quotes for the space character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first remove all CRLFs if the next `"` is at the end of a line:

```
result = subject.replace(/\r\n(?=[^"]*"$)/mg, " ");
```

Explanation:

```
\r\n    # Match a CRLF
(?=     # if and only if
 [^"]*  # it is followed by any number of non-quote characters
 "      # and a quote
 $      # at the end of a line
)       # End of lookahead.
```

This transforms your example into

```
SELECT * FROM CONVENIENT_ONE_LINE_QUERY
"SELECT * FROM THIS_QUERY WHERE IS_SPREAD_OVER == 123 ORDER BY MULTIPLE_LINES HAVING AND_IS_BETWEEN_QUOTES"
SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_CONVENIENT_ONE_LINER
```

[image]

Then, in a second step, remove the quotes:

```
result = subject.replace(/^"|"$/mg, "");
```

Comment: This solution is ignoring the many one-liners that don't have quotes - they would be concatenated.

Comment: @Lynx Kepler: You're right, I missed that case. I think my new solution works now.

Comment: Which flavor of regex did you use?
Which program did you run this regex in?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it in TextCrawler. But I'll try this RegexBuddy.

Comment: Did you remember to remove the slashes before copying it into RegexBuddy?

Comment: Yes, I did. The regex \r\n(?=[^"]*"$) returns zero matches, including in the example I posted here.

Comment: It works here perfectly. Do you know that you won't see the matches until you actually do the replace? After all, you're matching the newline, and that's not highlighted in a match in RegexBuddy.

Comment: I use the "Update Automatically" option and also tried clicking in the "Search-and-replace all matches". I played a little with this regex, but couldn't get it to work. If I copy and paste it as it is here, the first and second (the one between quotes) selects go unchanged but the third gets a space between each letter pair:
 S E L E C T   *   F R O M   A N O T H E R _ C O N V E N I E N T _ O N E _ L I N E R That's all.

Comment: And you did check the "^$ matches linebreaks" option?

Comment: Works perfectly now, many thanks! I really appreciated your dedication!

Answer (score 0):

With Perl you could do something like:

`s/^"([^"]*)"$/$s = $1; $s =~ s!(?:\n|\r)+! !g; $s/meg`